# Can I split a table through the correlation of its 2 columns?

Tags: data-mining

I've got a 2 column table (X, Y). Every row of the table says that the X on that row use the Y specified in the same row.

This are the sample data. https://jpst.it/L6I5

I'd like to cluster the table splitting it into smaller tables (less rows, same number of columns). I want to group X and Y which are 'similar'.

To make an example

- If 3 fields are used only by a single method they should be together.
- If two fields are always used together in every method they should be
  together.
- And so on.

Is there a method to do something similar?

Comment: Do you have a complete list of what ties two rows together? If so, can you (write code to) go through all the rows and denote if they belong together or not? If so, you can use this to create a distance metric and then cluster the data via k-means, GMM, etc. The main challenge here, I think, is getting a clear idea of what ties rows together in such a way that you want them in the same group.

Comment: @roundsquare: thanks. Is there any tool I can use to make some interactive experiments? like distance between 2 rows = high by default,  = 0 if the 2 rows share the value of the first or the second column? What is GMM?

Comment: unfortunately, I am not aware of any tools that would work in this way. My instinct would be to define the different things that could bring two rows together (i.e. reduce the distance) and then try a weighted average of them with various weights to see what gives you the best results (you will also need to define what makes some results better than others). GMM is "Gaussian Mixture Model" i.e. a "soft clustering" alternative to k-means where each point is a certain probability of belonging to each cluster (as opposed to k-means). Not sure if is appropriate for your application.